# Storing data in an array using Javascript Prototypical inheritance

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, constructor, arguments

Doing some javascript prototypical inheritance, I would like to push the arguments in my `Grades constructor` and do the storage manipulation and push the data  inside my `this.students` array using my storage method, and then use the values as I please within my other methods.

But the problem is that when I console log the constructor, it does what I need it to in terms of pushing the data in the `this.students` array but each object comes up as undefined.

This is weird because if I run the for loop inside the `Grades constructor` it will work perfectly. But I would like to have a separate method to do this, inside of within my `Grades constructor`

Any help in pointing me in the right direction would be great! Thanks!

```
function Grades(studentGrades) {

    if(!Array.isArray(studentGrades)) return true;

    this.students = [];
    this.studentGrades = arguments.length;
    this.numRows = 0;
    this.numColumns = 0;

    this.init();
}

/*
* Method to initialize functions
*/
Grades.prototype.init = function() {
    this.storage();
};

/*
* Method to store a list of grades in an array object
*/
Grades.prototype.storage = function() {
    for(var i=0; i < this.studentGrades; i++) {
        this.students.push(this.studentGrades[i]);
    }
};

/*
* Method to add grades
*/
Grades.prototype.addGrades = function(numRows, numColumns, initial) {
    for(this.numRows; this.numRows < this.students.length; this.numRows++ ) {

    }
};

/*
* Method to display the students average
*/
Grades.prototype.display = function() {
    // body...
};


var inputGrades = new Grades( [89,78,93,78], [83,67,93,98], [93,99,73,88] );


console.log(inputGrades);
```

Comment: @Teemu well the length of my argument is 3 in this case var inputGrades = new Grades( [89,78,93,78], [83,67,93,98], [93,99,73,88] ). As am just passing the objects inside the function, looking to manipulate the data of any arguments.length I put inside my Grades function.

Comment: You're setting `this.studentGrades = arguments.length;` (which is 3*), then later you're using `this.studentGrades`  as a number, and a line later you think it's an array??? *) `arguments` is an array-like object containing the arguments passed to a function.

Comment: @Teemu well if you console.log(this.studentGrades) it comes out to a length of 3

Comment: @Amechi Uhh, my bad, you're passing three arguments ... But `this.studentGrades` can't be a number and an array at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are some problems with your code, especially with Grades constructor :

```
function Grades(studentGrades) {

    if(!Array.isArray(studentGrades)) return true;

    this.students = [];
    this.studentGrades = arguments.length;
    this.numRows = 0;
    this.numColumns = 0;

    this.init();
}
```

You are using an array as parameter to the function but you are passing thtree parameters (arrays), I think this line:

```
var inputGrades = new Grades( [89,78,93,78], [83,67,93,98], [93,99,73,88] );
```

Should be like this:

```
var inputGrades = new Grades( [[89,78,93,78], [83,67,93,98], [93,99,73,88] ]);
```

And the following line `this.studentGrades = arguments.length;` is useless in the constructor and may cause problems in your code, and should be replaced with :

```
this.studentGrades = arguments;
```

Or if you pass an array of arrays like I did you can use:

```
this.studentGrades = studentGrades;
```

Comment: Thank you! this.studentGrades = arguments was the correct way to go! But I have a question, why shouldn't I use   this.studentGrades = arguments.length inside the constructor?

Comment: @Amechi Great, glad it helps. Concerning your last question, if we use `arguments.length` we will get a number the length of the array and if we asign this number to the `studentGrades` array its value will be a number and not an array.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is inside your storage function, originating from definition.

`this.studentGrades` is actually defined as the length of the array, not the array itself.

If you do not store the input array or pass it on through `init(inputGrades)` to `storage(inputGrades)`, then you cannot access the original input from your storage prototype.

Better: change constructor bit to:

```
this.students = [];
this.studentGrades = studentGrades;
```

And your function inside storage to:

```
for(var i=0; i < this.studentGrades.length; i++) {
    this.students.push(this.studentGrades[i]);
}
```

And you should be fine I think.

UPDATE: your original function call has a variable number of arguments.
Simplest way to get to complete answer is to change argument variable to:

```
var inputGrades = new Grades( [[89,78,93,78], [83,67,93,98], [93,99,73,88]]);
```

Now you send only one argument, an array of arrays.

Alternative: change the function to

```
function Grades() { // so no input argument

 if(!Array.isArray(studentGrades)) return true;

  this.students = [];
  this.studentGrades = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  this.numRows = 0;
  this.numColumns = 0;
```

And then you should be able to send in multiple arguments.